# combining date data validation and custom data valifation

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have googled this question and came across a question similar to mine. However, no one answered [it](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1000269-combining-a-data-validation-list-with-a-custom-formula-including-error-message.html)

I have in cell Q13 a date validation. However, I'd like to also add a custom formula in Q13 that only allows entry in Q13, if D13 is not blank (i.e. if D13 is blank, keep Q13 blank, if D13 is not blank, only allow date entries in Q13).

The custom validation I have in mind is:
=$D13<>""

However, it doesn't seem like there's a way to have both the date validation and custom validation in the same cell. I hope I'm wrong.

Could you please help.

Comment: could you add more of the code you have put in? What validation is it you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this custom validation

`=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D13)),NOT((ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(Q13,"mm/dd/yyyy"))))))`

Comment: You should change `NOT(ISBLANK())` to `<>""` as formulas won't  count as blank even if they return `""` ;)

Comment: @ChrisHarper Thanks mate. You're a champion. It worked fine.

Comment: Also, thanks @DirkReicheln for making the correction that I need.

Comment: @ChrisHarper What if I want it to have this custom validation: =$D13<>""
together with time instead of date. Is that possible?